# Samba shares won't accept my credentials with Ubuntu 22 LTS/Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I have the following share set up on Ubuntu 22 LTS:

```
[share]
path = /home/user/trunk
browsable = yes
writeable = yes
public = yes
```

I ran `sudo smbpasswd -a user` and set the password to be the same as the login password for Ubuntu. I then restarted the service with `sudo service smbd restart`.

I cannot connect to the share. When I try I get an "access denied" message in Windows 10, and it asks for my credentials again. This repeats in an endless loop.

The log file shows:

```
[2023/08/02 14:12:08.287659,  3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3954(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)

  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:151

[2023/08/02 14:12:08.307824,  1] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:242(smbd_smb2_tree_connect)

  smbd_smb2_tree_connect: reject request to share [IPC$] as 'UBUNTU22\user' without encryption or signing. Disconnecting.

[2023/08/02 14:12:08.307887,  3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3954(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)

  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:151

[2023/08/02 14:12:13.991527,  1] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:242(smbd_smb2_tree_connect)

  smbd_smb2_tree_connect: reject request to share [IPC$] as 'UBUNTU22\user' without encryption or signing. Disconnecting.

[2023/08/02 14:12:13.991679,  3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3954(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)

  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:151
```

Things I have tried:

- Setting the password to "password" and making sure it was typed correctly.
- Adding `ntlm auth = yes` to smb.conf
- Commenting out `map to guest = bad user` in smb.conf.
- Commenting out `usershare allow guests = yes` in smb.conf.
- Adding `security = user` to smb.conf.
- Removing samba entirely and re-installing it with apt.
- Trying to access the share directly via `\UBUNTU22\share'.

I also tried a fresh install of Ubuntu 22 and instead of editing smb.cong, I simply right clicked on a folder in my home directory and set up "local user sharing". That allows me to see the folder from Windows when browsing the machine, but I cannot open it as I get into the same credential loop as before. Interestingly, whatever that method does it does not appear to edit smb.conf because the shared folder does not appear in there.

Comment: (1) Is SELinux active? (2)  In `smb.conf`, is `security = user` (the default)? (3) Try [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/900440/samba-configuration-statusnt-status-access-denied)

Comment: security=user was not the default.  I tried the `sestatus` command but it was not installed, so I guess the answer is no.

Comment: I have this working. I had to do some minor repairs to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but then it all works.   Go through this article in detail and follow the steps https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba

Comment: Thanks @John, but I did follow that article previously and it didn't work. Kind of amazing that the LTS version has broken Samba out of the box.

Comment: It is all working here.

Comment: I know (can see) you reinstalled Ubuntu.  Try this:  Remove samba, then sudo apt-get --fix-missing update   ....   followed by ....  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade   ....   Restart install Samba, set up and try again.

Comment: Also see if (from Ubuntu) you can:   SMB://IPofWindows/folder and authenticate. Does that work?  @user3241

Comment: I posted a complete answer including complete restarts at the end. Hopefully you will see value in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reboot Ubuntu, twice. I have no idea why the second reboot worked, I initially rebooted to see if it would work, gave up for the day, and in the morning it was letting me browse the share with read/write access.

Possibly it is some kind of caching issue, but I'm not sure if it is on the Linux or Windows side. Reboot everything like it's 1995 I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide to installing and configuring Samba that is worth reviewing and following.

[Install and configure Samba](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba)

Key pointst:

> Install / reinstall Samba and ensure it is working.
>
> Ensure smb.conf is properly configured. sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf.
>
> Add the following lines at the bottom of the file:     [sambashare}
> comment = Samba on Ubuntu path = /home//sambashare read only
> = no browsable = yes
>
> Restart the samba service:   sudo service smbd restart     Update the
> firewall rules if necessary:  sudo ufw allow samba
>
> Add the user: sudo smbpasswd -a    and password
>
> In Windows: \192.168.x.y where this is the IP of the Linux Machine

All this has been tested and works.

You might have restarted systems along the way.

At the end do complete restarts of both systems to be sure everything has been reset and ensure you can ping both ways.

Comment: As I said, merely restarting the service was not enough.

Comment: I did add to do complete OS restarts on all systems. I merely captured key points from the link so as not to have a blind link. The complete answer covers all I did and your restarts as well. Restarts will restart all services which likely helped.